# Finding the value of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil}\frac{k}{2n-k}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: combinatorics, limits, summation

I am trying to find the exact value of
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil-1}\frac{2n-2k}{2n-k}
$$
for any $\alpha>0$. By some simple bounds I have found that
$$
e^{-\alpha^2}\lesssim\prod_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil-1}\frac{2n-2k}{2n-k}\lesssim e^{-\alpha^2/4}\quad\text{as }n\to\infty,
$$
so I know that I am considering the correct asymptotics, i.e. there is asymptotically the correct number of factors in the product. My idea was then to show that I am not losing anything in my upper bound. Thus, I have also shown that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil-1}\frac{2n-2k}{2n-k}\sim\exp\bigg(-\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil-1}\frac{k}{2n-k}\bigg),
$$
i.e. the two are asymptotically equivalent, meaning that their quotient tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. This leaves me with finding the limit of the sum. The $-1$ in the upper limit is asymptotically negligable, so we are looking to find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil}\frac{k}{2n-k},
$$
if the limit exists, which I believe to be the case. I have tried to write it as a Riemann-sum as follows:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil}\frac{\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}}{2-\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
$$
but alas, this is only almost a Riemann-sum, at the $k/\sqrt{n}$ in the denominator is divided by $\sqrt{n}$ too much.

WolframAlpha says, without explanation, that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{k}{2n-k}=-2n\psi^{(0)}(m-2n)-n+2n\psi^{(0)}(1-2n)+1,
$$
where $m\leq 2n$ and $\psi^{(0)}$ is the digamma function. I have no clue how one would show this, but I'm guessing that this calculation would suffice in finding the limit.

Edit: found an error in the upper bound, which I have corrected.

Comment: Doesn't Stirling's formula give a usable approximation to your product?  And isn't the approximation $k/(2n-k)\approx k/(2n)$ good enough in your sum?

Comment: I wonder if the asymptotics could be $\exp(-\alpha^2/4)$ for the initial formula

Comment: What makes you think that, Claude?

Comment: Say intuition probably

Comment: Take $\alpha=2$ and $n=10^8$. The exact result is $A=0.3678610461$  while the approximation gives $\log(A)=-\frac{20001}{20000}$which gives $A=0.3678610477$

Comment: Looks like you were both right, kimchi lover and Claude! Thanks a lot for your help. I have looked at my upper bound again and found an error, so the upper bound should indeed be $e^{-\alpha^2/4}$, matching your approximation and intuition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for the sum $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt n\rceil}\frac k{2n-k}$.  For all $k$ in the range of summation, $0<k<1+\sqrt n \alpha$, so
$$ \frac k{2n}\le\frac k{2n-k}\le\frac k{2n-(1+\sqrt n \alpha)} = \frac k{2n}\times\frac{2n}{2n-(1+\sqrt n \alpha)}.$$
Hence $$ \frac1 {2n} \frac {\lceil\alpha\sqrt n\rceil(\lceil\alpha\sqrt n\rceil+1)}2 
\le S_n \le \frac1 {2n} \frac {\lceil\alpha\sqrt n\rceil(\lceil\alpha\sqrt n\rceil+1)}2
\times\frac{2n}{2n-(1+\sqrt n \alpha)}.$$
The upper and lower bounds both converge to $\alpha^2/4$.

Answer (score 3):

*For the initial problem.*

$$A=\prod_{k=1}^{p}\frac{2n-2k}{2n-k}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p} (2n-2k) } { \prod_{k=1}^{p} (2n-k) }=2^p\frac{ (1-n)_p}{(1-2 n)_p}$$ $$A=\frac{2^{p-2 n}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right) \Gamma (-n+p+1)}{\Gamma (-2
   n+p+1)}$$

Now, let $p=\alpha \sqrt n -1$
$$A=\frac{2^{\alpha  \sqrt{n}-2 n-1}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right) \Gamma \left(\sqrt{n}
   \alpha -n\right)}{\Gamma \left(\sqrt{n} \alpha -2 n\right)}$$

Taking logarithms and series expansion for large $n$ assuming $0 <\alpha<\sqrt n$

$$\log(A)=-\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}-\frac{\alpha  \left(\alpha^2-2\right)}{8\sqrt n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

**Edit**

It does not make any problem to write
$$\log(A)=-\frac{\alpha ^2}{4}\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac {a_i}{n^{\frac i2}} \right)$$

$$a_1=\frac{\alpha ^2-2}{2 \alpha } \qquad a_2=\frac{7 \alpha ^2-18}{24}\qquad a_3= \frac{9 \alpha ^4-28 \alpha ^2+12}{48 \alpha }$$
$$a_4=\frac{62 \alpha ^4-225 \alpha ^2+140}{480}\qquad a_5=\frac{\alpha  \left(15 \alpha ^4-62 \alpha ^2+50\right)}{160} $$ Using the above terms, it seems to work quite decently even for small values of $n$.

Some numbers for $\alpha=2$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
  9 & 0.28994447 & 0.28959276 \\
 16 & 0.31329694 & 0.31323693 \\
 25 & 0.32586416 & 0.32584887 \\
 36 & 0.33371439 & 0.33370937 \\
 49 & 0.33908626 & 0.33908429 \\
 64 & 0.34299493 & 0.34299406 \\
 81 & 0.34596735 & 0.34596693 \\
 100 & 0.34830436 & 0.34830413 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

**A side note**

$$S_m=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{k}{2n-k}=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{k-2n+2n}{2n-k}=-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}1+2n\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac 1{2n-k}$$
$$S_m=2n(H_{-2 n}-H_{m-2 n-1})-(m-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

@kimchilover's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/457779/kimchi-lover) was correct, the approximation $k/(2n-k)\approx k/2n$ is sufficient. To quantify the error, we write
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{k}{2n-k}
&=\frac{k}{2n}+\left(\frac{k}{2n}\right)^2+\left(\frac{k}{2n}\right)^3+\dots
\\&=\frac{k}{2n}+O\left(\left(\frac{k}{2n}\right)^2\right)
\\&=\frac{k}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\alpha \sqrt n}\frac{k}{2n-k}
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\alpha \sqrt n}\left(\frac{k}{2n}+O(1/n)\right)
\\&=\frac{(\alpha \sqrt n)^2}{2\cdot 2n}+O(1/\sqrt n)
\\&=\frac{\alpha^2}4+O(1/\sqrt n)
\end{align}
$$
Finally, we get

$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\lceil\alpha\sqrt{n}\rceil-1}\frac{2n-2k}{2n-k}
=\exp\bigg(-\frac{\alpha^2}4+O(1/\sqrt n)
\bigg)\sim \exp\left(\frac{-\alpha^2}{4}\right)
$$